# Search by user name not working from mobile

Tags: feature-request, search, mobile-web

When I go to https://stackoverflow.com/users and start typing a username, it gives me a list of suggestions for usernames, this means it is working perfectly from my laptop. But, when I search users from mobile devices, `onblur` simply leads to page refresh.

I am wondering why there is no search button for mobile users? It would be really useful if there was a search button for mobile browsers.

Comment: Hmmmm... maybe some OS/browser info is in order. It works fine for me on Android GB+Dolphin.

Answer (score -1):

I am also using android phone, the problem you are talking about, is not a bug in Stack overflow scripts, It is because of browser settings. 
I know because I'd also faced same problem.
But there is a solution
You are using mobile site, change it with full site, this will bring you those features that are not working at present in your mobile. This option is available in footer links.

Comment: The OP did not say they were on Android - that was me. Further, the user search works fine for me, and should work on all supported browsers. This post is about that apparent bug, not asking for a workaround..